# initial data for StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

what should be the initialData for StreamProvider.value 
I'm unable to initialize it to null

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
       value: DatabaseService.withoutUID().brews,
       initialData: null,
       ......
```

initialData:null is showing an error :
`The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'.`

Below is the DatabaseService helper class

```
class DatabaseService{

  final String uid;

  DatabaseService(this.uid);
  DatabaseService.withoutUID():uid="" ;


  //collection reference
  final CollectionReference brewCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews');

  Future updateUserData(String sugars, String name, int strength) async{
    return await brewCollection.doc(uid).set({
      "sugars": sugars,
      "name" : name,
      "strength" : strength,
    });
  }

  //get brews stream
  Stream<QuerySnapshot>? get brews{
    return brewCollection.snapshots();
  }

}
```

Here I'm calling that stream

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
      value: DatabaseService.withoutUID().brews,
      initialData: null,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          title: Text("Brew Crew"),
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              }, .......
```

In the tutorial, I'm following they are using the flutter version where `initialData` is not compulsory in my case `(flutter v 2.2.3)` it is mandatory to provide `initialData` while we are using `StreamProvider`.
So I wondering what value I should provide there.

BTW I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10PcEkQsF9Y&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=18) tutorial from `The net ninja` channel in yt

Comment: yes, you cant give null to initial data... before it fetch data you have to give a initial data to the value...

Comment: Agreed, but I'm asking what value can we put there? Is there something like a default value?

Comment: update your question with where you are calling the DatabaseService.withoutUID().brews and where u want to use it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should replace `QuerySnapshot with List<Brew>.`
and  your `initialData: []`
and everything should work fine.

```
  class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService(this.uid);

  DatabaseService.withoutUID() : uid = "";

  //collection reference
  final CollectionReference brewCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews');

  Future updateUserData(String sugars, String name, int strength) async {
    return await brewCollection.doc(uid).set({
      "sugars": sugars,
      "name": name,
      "strength": strength,
    });
  }

  //get brews stream
  Stream<Brew>? get brews {
    return brewCollection.snapshots();
  }

  List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      //print(doc.data);
      return Brew(
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
          strength: doc.data['strength'] ?? 0,
          sugars: doc.data['sugars'] ?? '0');
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

your home.dart

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Brew>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService.withoutUID().brews,
      initialData: [],
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          title: Text("Brew Crew"),
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              }, .......
```

Comment: I couldn't get, where did we use "_brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot)" in this code?

Comment: I think it should be mapped like
 Stream<Brew>? get brews {
    return brewCollection.snapshots().map(_brewListFromSnapshot);
  }

Comment: It's an old youtube tutorial that uses an old version of flutter. Called flutter firebase app tutorial in (the net ninja channel) you can watch it to find the complete code and explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of returning a "StreamProvider.value", you can simple return "StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value".
Then the initial value will accept "null" values.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 4):

make QuerySnapshot nullable by adding ? after it :

```
return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value(
  initialData: null,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value(
  initialData: [],
```

Comment: Hello @Manish-Sachu It's really nice that you want to contribute. Next time writing answer, please add some reasoning/explanation possibly reference to documentation. Pasting just a snippet of code is not the best way to help others. I see a value in brevity of your answer and that's why I am not going to recommend it for deletion (otherwise it is basically a duplicate of already selected answer). Please improve it by adding some justification.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem, is just to make the  nullable by adding '?'
like:-StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value

Comment: Hi Aman. Welcome :) This is a duplicate of an of existing answer, by @Latino. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.